# Possible to Authenticate with an website with POST / Download CAPTCHA

Tags: java, forms-authentication, captcha, httpclient, http-authentication

I've often wanted to create applications that provide a simpler front-end to other websites that require users to login before the pages I want to use can be accessed. I was wondering, if

(1) any website with a POST to an http page can be authenticated by POSTing

```
postField1name=pf1Value&postField2name=pf2Value
```

to the website, if that's true how can you inspect the HTML to POST correctly?

(2) I wanted to know if you could parse HTML, say for a sign up form, and display all the fields in an application UI, including downloading a Captcha, and displaying it to the user, and allowing them to type the value in, to send back to the website, and process the response.

Also if anyone knows how I might accomplish (2) using Apache HTTP Client in java, I'd greatly appreciate it!

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/index.html

Comment: what is the question? :)

Comment: Want to mention that I want to do it in Java. (Specifically Android)

Answer (score 0):

(1) An easy way to find out what's actually being POST'd is to look at the actual HTTP requests. You can do that with a tool like [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/). Then have your script simulate that.

(2) Yes. You can use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), which is excellent for things like this.

Comment: So for example, Their post method for captcha is actually to send what the user typed. I'm assuming they check it somehow against the captcha that was generated when the page was created. How do I make sure that will work?

Comment: @Janine Is this running on a server or the client?

Comment: Client, connecting to third part server

Comment: So you are writing a client that acts like a web browser?

Comment: Yes, I have a client with the same fields as the website, and POST and GET in the same manner. After using POST to authenticate with the site, one of the pages an authenticated user can see is one that displays a CAPTCHA and has a field which POSTs the user's entry. I want to be able to show the same Captcha to the user, so the correct "answer" is submitted

Comment: I used your suggestion LiveHTTPHeaders, which is great! Now I think all I will have to do is know that it is possible to do what I want with the CAPTCHA, before I begin this project

Answer (score 0):

(1) Try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). There's actually a lot of options for authentication.

(2) Try [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)